# How do i use press keys in Robot Framework to send date in calender popup in chrome

Tags: datepicker, robotframework, chrome-web-driver

I have to automate selecting a date from date picker. I am able to click the field and type in a date. In Firefox I was able to use press key to type date whereas the same test when run in chrome gives the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

I tried setting focus before using press key. Set focus passes but when it tries to press keys, I get this error.

my code looks like this(this works fine in firefox):

```
Click Element  xpath=//div[@class='ant-calendar-date-input-wrap']
    press key  xpath=//div[@class='ant-calendar-date-input-wrap']|{date_to_select}
```

[[image]

Comment: Please put your code in the "code" format to make it easier to read and check for errors. Also, according to Todor (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790516/cant-press-enter-in-selenium2library), you need the second argument. I'm not seeing it in your code.

Comment: thanks Brandon, the second argument is a variable ${date_to_select}.I actually found out a workaround by using 'Input Text' instead of 'send keys'

Comment: Not without the dollar sign in front of it.

Comment: You are right, I missed the dollar sign!

Comment: Assuming `${date_to_select}` is set to the correct code for the `Enter` key, that should work.

Comment: it was still not working for chrome. From researching, i found that this is an existing bug in chrome driver. Anyways the workaround of using Input Text worked from chrome.

Comment: If that's the case, then post your answer so this question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: This worked in Chrome:                                                                           
Input Text  xpath=//*[@class='ant-calendar-date-input-wrap']/input  ${date_to_select}

Comment: As an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this by using 'Input Text' instead of Send Keys for chrome.Here is the code that worked:
Input Text xpath=//*[@class='ant-calendar-date-input-wrap']/input ${date_to_select}